# Block insert operation and record the attempt on another audit table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

I am trying to block an insert operation between 7pm and 12 am. Everything is working fine except that the trigger is firing the exception before it inserted on the audit table. my question is how can I both block the operation and record the attempt at the same time?

Here is what I have tried.

````
    Attempt_Date        DATE,
    Operation       VARCHAR2(10),
    Table_Affected  VARCHAR2(10));


Create or replace trigger audit_trigger 
Before insert or update on rents 
declare
    Period_error EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    If TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'HH24MMSS' ) BETWEEN '060000' AND '100000' THEN
    begin
        RAISE Period_error;
                IF INSERTING THEN
                    INSERT INTO Rent_Audit VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Insert', 'Rents');
                End if;
            
                IF UPDATING THEN
                    INSERT INTO Rent_Audit VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Update', 'Rents');
                End if;
            
    EXCEPTION
        When Period_error THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'insertion not allowed on this time');
    end;
    end if;
END;```
````

Comment: Besides needing to be *PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION* and the action sequence you have another fatal issue.  The `IF` will not work as intended, both the to_char format and the values tested are incorrect. First the format: `HH24MMSS` will return hour of day ('00' to '23'), **month** ('01' to '12'), and seconds ('00' to '59').   (minuets is MI not MM). (see Datetime Format Elements in [SQL language reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210here).

Comment: Now for the values. In the description you indicate times `7 PM and 12 AM` yet you test for `6 AM to 10 AM` . These values need to be `190000` and `235959` respectively. So your statement needs to read `to_char(sysdate, 'hh24miss') between '190000' and '235959'` (`240000` works as it will never be returned, but as a time of day would be invalid.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to log it, then

- trigger has to be autonomous transaction (otherwise `RAISE` would prevent insertion into `rent_audit` as well)

  - which also means that it has to `commit`
- raise exception AFTER you inserted a row into `rent_audit`

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON rents
DECLARE
   period_error  EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   IF TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24MMSS') BETWEEN '060000' AND '100000'
   THEN
      BEGIN
         IF INSERTING
         THEN
            INSERT INTO rent_audit
                 VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Insert', 'Rents');
         END IF;

         IF UPDATING
         THEN
            INSERT INTO rent_audit
                 VALUES (SYSDATE, 'Update', 'Rents');
         END IF;

         COMMIT;
         RAISE period_error;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN period_error
         THEN
            raise_application_error (-20001,
                                     'insertion not allowed on this time');
      END;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Did the above answer solve your issue? If so kindly accept it. This helps future users having the same or similar issue, and removes it from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered. If it did not solve your issue then what remains?